# Count time for multiple for cycles

Tags: c, for-loop, time, clock

Im trying to count time of different for cycles inside my program but I can only do it for one at the same time.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SEED 35791246

main(int argc, char* argv)
{
   int niter=20000;
   int niter1=100000;
   int niter2=1000000;
   int niter3=10000000;
   double x,y;
   int i,count=0; 
   double z;
   double pi;


   clock_t begin = clock();

   srand(SEED);
   count=0;
   for ( i=0; i<niter; i++) {
      x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      z = x*x+y*y;
      if (z<=1) count++;
      }
   pi=(double)count/niter*4;
   printf("Number of variables %d , Pi estimate: %g \n",niter,pi);

   clock_t end = clock();
   double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Time Spent: %f  seconds\n", time_spent);


   srand(SEED);
   count=0;
   for ( i=0; i<niter1; i++) {
      x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
      z = x*x+y*y;
      if (z<=1) count++;
      }
   pi=(double)count/niter1*4;
   printf("Number of variables %d , Pi estimate %g \n",niter1,pi);
}
```

When I try to add another "clock_t begin = clock();" for the second loop I get an error. How can I get time spent on each for cycle?

Comment: Maybe you need to use `begin = clock();` the second time, not `clock_t begin = clock();`.

Comment: Your timing will include both the call to `srand` and (much worse) the output to the console. That `printf` call will skew the timing of the loop by a lot.

Comment: @FiddlingBits still no luck.

Comment: `clock()` is likely to have low resolution - you can check what it is by printing the value of  `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.  I'd be surprised if it was as high as `1000` - which would give `ms` resolution.  The number of iterations of the loop will need to be very large before you even measure one tick.

Comment: Here's a general tip when you have multiple pieces of code looking just about the same: Use *functions*. Put the loop doing the calculation in a function, and pass `niter` as argument. Return the `count`. Get the `clock` before and after the call to time the loop.